# Error while using findNonZero in openCV python

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying this code in openCV

`points = cv2.findNonZero(res)`

What is the meaning of this error? and how should I resolve it?

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-qjdp5db9\opencv\modules\core\src\count_non_zero.dispatch.cpp:162: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.channels() == 1 && src.dims == 2 in function 'cv::findNonZero'`

Comment: `src.channels() == 1` means it must be single-channel. `src.dims == 2` means it must be a two-dimensional array. either or both of these were violated. that is what the assertion tells you.

Answer (score 1):

"res" must be a single-channel array (type CV_8UC1)

Try to do the following before call cv2.findNonZero(res):

```
res = cv2.cvtColor(res, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Or any other conversion that makes "res" valid for findNonZero() call.